# Unable to clear Hibernate queryCache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails-orm, spring-orm

While using Hibernate-core-5.1.14 I was using `sessionFactory.getQueryCache().clear()` to clear Query Cache. After migrating to Hibernate-core-5.4.18 since now no such method getQueryCache() is available SessionFactoryImpl so I am unable to clear it.

On referring to migration documents [sessionfactory-hierarchy-cleanup](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2/migration-guide.adoc#sessionfactory-hierarchy-cleanup) I got to know that

> SessionFactory and SessionFactoryImplementor each had a number of methods dealing with cache regions. Many of these methods have been deprecated since 5.0 and those will be removed. However, the functionality has been moved into the org.hibernate.Cache and org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor contracts helping implement JPA’s javax.persistence.Cache role.

Then on searching found `getDefaultQueryCache()` as alternative provided by Hibernate available in `org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor`. In order to clear Query Cache I tried using it like `CacheImplementor.getDefaultQueryResultsCache().clear()` but I am unable to get QueryCache only on call of `getDefaultQueryCache()`. Any hint or guidance regarding getting to solution is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure you query caching is enabled you can enabled by

```
<property
    name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"
value="true" />
```

second individual queries are not cached ,

> most queries do not benefit from caching or their results. So by default, individual queries are not cached even after enabling query caching. Each particular query that needs to be cached must be manually set as cacheable. This way, the query looks for existing cache results or adds the query results to the cache when being executed.

you can read [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-query) query caching section.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this [document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching).

Evicting entities with JPA

```
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict( Person.class );
```

Evicting entities with Hibernate native API

```
session.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictQueryRegion( "query.cache.person" );
```